# Как сделать горизонтальный выбор radiobutton с текстом?

Tags: java, android, xml

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать горизонтальный выбор radiobutton с текстом? 
Думаю использовать HorizontalScrollView, но не знаю как добавить добавить текст.

Comment: textview под image, не? Или если мне не изменяет память, то к radiobutton так же как и к toggle прилагается текст рядом с коробки)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

Если нужно чтоб текст располагался ниже кнопки

```
<RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:button="@null"
        android:drawableTop="your_drawable"/>
```